# Trouble with math in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I make script that does the following:

- Grab how much cash is available
- Grab the product price
- Tell how much of product can be bought with what i have and how much will be leftover.

```
var valCash = prompt("How much do you have?");
var price = prompt("Whats the product price?");
var buying = valCash / price;
console.log(buying);
var buyingLeftover = valCash - (buying * price);
console.log(buyingLeftover);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHbue.png]

Comment: `valCash` and `price` are strings. use `parseFloat`.

Comment: Your output tells you that you can buy 8 point something product entities with your money. So before multiplying `buying * price`, you will have to remove the decimals from `buying`. Hint `Math.floor()`

Comment: Welcome to SO Geovani! Sounds to me like you could use a `while` loop.  Check whether the amount left is greater than the cost of another item, if it is, subtract another item. Otherwise, return the remainder and the number of items (a counter).

Remember that SO is meant to provide questions that will be useful to many people, not just solve your problem, so try to do as much background research as possible to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @DanielA.White, shouldn't matter in this context.  They'll be converted to numbers.

Comment: @GeovaniC:  `buying = valCash /price`.  Therefore, `valCash = buying * price`.  Therefore, `buyingLeftover` will always be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math is the problem, not your JavaScript. You first find you can buy X amount of something and store that in "buying". However, you then go on to *always* produce 0.

```
var buying = valCash / price;
var buyingLeftover = valCash - (buying * price);
```

It is easy to see, just use a substitution.

```
var buying = valCash / price;
var buyingLeftover = valCash - ( (valCash / price) * price);
```

which is

```
var buying = valCash / price;
var buyingLeftover = valCash - valCash;
```

In order to not get 0 you would need to avoid purchasing partial products. This means only whole numbers. You can do this by parsing the number as an integer

```
var buyingLeftover = valCash - (parseInt(buying,10) * price);
```

And now you will get the leftover from purchasing

```
var valCash = 8;//prompt("How much do you have?");
var price = 6;//prompt("Whats the product price?");
var buying = valCash / price;
console.log(buying);//1.3333333333333333
var buyingLeftover = valCash - (parseInt(buying,10) * price);
console.log(buyingLeftover);//2
```

Comment: but how can i avoid getting a zero?

Comment: @GeovaniC - See edits. Ensure that partial products are not purchased by parsing the integer from the floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

> buying = valCash / price (1)
>
> buyingLeftover = valCash - (buying * price) (2)

...... (1) in (2) ......

> buyingLeftover = valCash - ((valCash / price) * price)
>
> buyingLeftover = valCash - (valCash)
>
> buyingLeftover = 0